# if {arena1.use} isn't set: or if {arena1.use} is false: doesn't work, but else does?

Tags: minecraft

I currently have an issue with Skript (minecraft related skript) and there is an interesting thing here. I use `if {arena1.use} isn't set:` or `if {arena1.use} is false:` and it doesn't work, but when I use `else:` it does? It's quite a bizzare thing, but I was hoping that someone could help me out here. The reason I can't use `else:` is due to me wanting to have multiple arenas in my code.

This is the code:

```
command /duel [<text>] [<player>]:
    aliases: /duels
    usage: '&a/duel &f(&einvite&f/&aaccept&f/&creject&f) &d<player>'
    permission: cinox.duels
    permission message: &cYou don't have the correct permissions to use this command!
    trigger:
        if arg-1 isn't set:
            send "&cInvalid usage!"
            send "&a/duel &f(&einvite&f/&baccept&f/&creject&f) &d<player>"
            stop
        if arg-1 is "invite":
            if arg-2 isn't set:
                send "&cInvalid usage!"
                send "&f/duel invite <player>"
                stop
            else:
                if arg-2 isn't online:
                    send "&cThat player isn't online!"
                    stop
                else:
                    if arg-2 is player:
                        send "&cYou can't invite yourself to a duel!"
                    else:
                        set {%player%.inviteduel.%arg-2%} to true
                        send "&aInvite send to %arg-2%!"
                        send "&e&lInvite expires in &c30&e seconds!"
                        send "&a%player% wants challenge with you!" to arg-2
                        send "&e&l/duel (accept/reject) %player%" to arg-2
                        wait "30 seconds" parsed as timespan
                        {%player%.inviteduel.%arg-2%} is true
                        send "&cYour duel invite to &3%arg-2% &cis expired" to player
                        send "&cYour duel invite from &3%player% &cis expired" to arg-2
                        set {%player%.inviteduel.%arg-2%} to false
                        stop
        if arg-1 is "accept":
            if arg-2 isn't set:
                send "&cInvalid usage!"
                send "&f/duel accept <player>"
                stop
            else:
                if arg-2 isn't online:
                    send "&cThat player isn't online!"
                    stop
                else:
                    if arg-2 is player:
                        send "&cYou can't accept your own duel request!"
                    else:
                        if {%arg-2%.inviteduel.%player%} is true:
                            set {%arg-2%.inviteduel.%player%} to false
                            if {arena1.use} is true:
                                send "Sorry, arena is on use. Wait small bit and try again"
                                send "Sorry, arena is on use. Wait small bit and try again" to arg-2
                                stop
                            if {arena1.use} isn't set: # here is the issue
                                send "test"
                                set {arena1.use} to true
                                send "&aYour duel invite has accepted by &e%player%" to arg-2
                                send "&aYou've accepted the duel invite by &e%arg-2%"
                                send "&aTeleporting you in a few seconds..." to arg-2
                                send "&aTeleporting you in a few seconds..."
                                wait 3 seconds
                                make console execute command "effect clear %player%"
                                make console execute command "effect clear %arg-2%"
                                teleport player to location(-48, 116, 1104, world "world_the_end")
                                teleport arg-2 to location(45, 116, 1010, world "world_the_end")
                        else:
                            send "&cThere is no active duel request!"
        if arg-1 is "reject":
            if arg-2 isn't set:
                send "&cInvalid usage!"
                send "&f/duel reject <player>"
                stop
            else:
                if arg-2 isn't online:
                    send "&cThat player isn't online!"
                    stop
                else:
                    if arg-2 is player:
                        send "&cYou can't reject your own duel request!"
                    else:
                        send "&cYou've rejected a duels invite from &6%arg-2%&c!"
                        send "&6%player% &crejected your duels invite!" to arg-2
                        stop

command /clearallarena:
    permission: cinox.clearallarena
    permission message: &cYou don't have the correct permissions to use this command!
    trigger:
        set {arena1.use} to false
        send "&aDone!"

command /profile:
  trigger:
    if {gamesp.%player's uuid%} is not set:
      set {gamesp.%player's uuid%} to 0
    if {wins.%player's uuid%} is not set:
      set {wins.%player's uuid%} to 0
    if {loses.%player's uuid%} is not set:
      set {loses.%player's uuid%} to 0
    wait 5 ticks
    open chest with 1 row named "&3&lProfile: &b%player%" to player
    wait 3 ticks
    format slot 0 of player with red glass named "&7" to close
    format slot 1 of player with red glass named "&7" to close
    format slot 2 of player with red glass named "&7" to close
    format slot 3 of player with arrow named "&7Loses: &c&l%{loses.%player's uuid%}%" to close
    format slot 4 of player with diamond named "&7Wins: &e&l%{wins.%player's uuid%}%" to close
    format slot 5 of player with blaze rod named "&7Games played: &3&l%{gamesp.%player's uuid%}%" to close
    format slot 6 of player with red glass named "&7" to close
    format slot 7 of player with red glass named "&7" to close
    format slot 8 of player with red glass named "&7" to close

command /cleararena [<integer>]:
    permission: cinox.cleararena
    permission message: &cYou don't have the correct permissions to use this command!
    trigger:
        if arg-1 isn't set:
            send "&cYou must mention an arena to clear!"
            stop
        if arg-1 is 1:
            if {arena1.use} is true:
                set {arena1.use} to false
                send "&aDone!"
            else:
                send "&cThat arena isn't active!"
        else:
            send "&cNo duels arena found!"
```

Comment: I suggest you to make a [mre] but minimal ! Also, I think you should use `if {arena1.use} isn't set:` before `if {arena1.use} is true:`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use else if to put multiple else's and therefore multiple arenas into play.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).